# Android ConstraintLayout - Place many elements below one top element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am developing an Android app and the layout I am currently working on is a ConstraintLayout.
I need to place three elements below one "top" element, like this:

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVmWE.png)

Using horizontal and vertical chains I managed to do it like this:

[How it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ4h7.png)

However, I don't know how to place the first and the third small box also directly below the big box. I understand that I somehow need a vertical chain, but I don't know how to do it because I only have one big box I can chain them to and I already used it for the small box in the middle.
The only thing I can think of is to add e.g. TextViews without a text to both sides of the big box and then chain the other two boxes to them, but is there maybe a more elegant solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a vertical chain. Constrain the tops of the smaller boxes to the bottom of the big box and remove the bottom constraints on the little boxes. If you still have trouble, post your XML.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I somehow thought it is necessary to have constraints for all four sides.

Comment: Vertical and horizontal constraints are required but doesn't mean top/bottom or left/right. One constraint is each dimension is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow something like the following code snippet to achieve your desired UI,

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <View android:id="@+id/topView" />
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/bottomView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/bottomView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/bottomView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bottomView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/bottomView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```